# Count number of rehashing in unordered map

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

What is the right way to evaluate the unordered_map performance? [C++14]

In my code, I am using std::unordered_map very extensively in the order of billions of keys. For the purpose of performance I wished to know the behavior of unordered_map as how many times it had to rehash and all other parameter (how many buckets? How many buckets where empty before rehashing?). I know stl provides the number of buckets. But what else would be needed to profile or what do you use to analyze?

Comment: *"I know stl provides the number of buckets?"* Sad but true. The bucket interface should never have existed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Like many std containers, unordered_map is mandated to grow in size exponentially.  The exact rate is implementation defined; you can examine the specs of your implementation or its source code.

How it resizes is deterministic.  If you wrapped it in a shim, you could detect these resizes by examining bucket_count before and after each operation that is permitted to grow the container.

You can iterate over the buckets:

```
template<class UnorderedMeow>
std::size_t empty_buckets( UnorderedMeow&& meow ) {
  std::size_t r = 0;
  auto buckets = meow.buckets_count();
  for (decltype(buckets) i = 0; i < buckets; ++i)
    if (meow.bucket_size(i)==0)
      ++r;
  return r;
}
```

to find out how many are empty.

If you use inheritance based composition and override only those you know can add/remove stuff...

```
template<class Base>
struct instrumented_unordered_map:Base {
  using Self = instrumented_unordered_map;
  using Base::Base;
  using key_type = Base::key_type; // etc
  struct instrument {
    Self* self;
    instrument( Self* s ):self(s) {
      self->start_instrument();
    }
    ~instrument() {
      self->end_instrument();
    }
  };
  struct instrument_state {
    // blah
  };
  instrument_state state;
  void start_instrument() {
    // populate state
  }
  void end_instrument() {
    // extract from state, generate report
  }
  decltype(auto) operator[]( key_type const& key ) {
    instrument _(this);
    return Base::operator[](key);
  }
  // etc  
};
```